# Как отправить и получить ассоциативный массив в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

изучаю Laravel. Не могу получить массив в blade. Будьте добры.

Controller:

```html
$a = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
$b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];

for ($i=0; $i<count($b); $i++){
     $film[$i] = [
                "a" => $a[$i],
                "b" => $b[$i],
             ];
    }
    
//     echo $film[2]["a"].'   -  ';
//     echo $film[1]["b"].'<br />';

return view('example')->with('data',$film);
```

view example.blade.php:

```html
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Hello,
     @foreach($data[2] as $link)
            <a href="{{ $link['a']}}">{{ $link['b']}}</a>
     @endforeach
          </h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Массив `$a` не объявлен.

Comment: исправил. но даже если так.

Comment: А почему `foreach($data[2]` а не просто `foreach($data`?

Comment: отлично так работает. но это только внутри @foreach. А могу ли вызвать в blade например вот так: {{ $film[2]["a"] }} как в контроллере вне цикла?

Comment: Ну вызовите и посмотрите что будет, зачем спрашивать?

Comment: Лицо покраснело ))   написал в blade вот так {{ $data[3]['a'] }}. И Наконец то результат, который я хотел. Спасибо бро.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
 $a = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
 $b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];

 return view('index', compact('a', 'b'));
```

View

```
<html>
    <body>    
         <h1>Hello,
            @foreach($a as $item)
               <p>{{ $item }}</p>
            @endforeach
         </h1>    
    </body>
</html>
```